# Repopulate Dropdown List After Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I'm still wet behind the ears with JavaScript as a whole, but I'm scratching my head on this one, ASP.Net MVC 4 style. Whenever a particular country is selected, I'd like to populate a dropdown list ONLY with cities from that country. Simple concept, but a lot of pieces to make it work. This is a project I had no hand in designing, so this first part is legacy code. Here is the initial declaration of my select list for cities.

```
<div id="city_info" style="display: none">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Position.CityId, "City *", new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Position.CityId, ViewBag.Cities as SelectList, string.Empty, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Position.CityId)
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the Ajax call I wrote to get a JSON object containing all the cities {int id, String name}.

```
 $.get('@Url.Action("GetCitiesByCountryId", "Ajax")', 
       { id: $('option:selected', $(this)).value() }, 
       function(data) {
           //What goes here? 
       });
```

I'm not sure what labels or ids need to be targeted, and then do I simply say "data as SelectList?" I'm a bit lost on both the where and how at this stage.

Comment: Refer also [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) for complete example with all the code necessary in the controller to make cascading dropdownlists work correctly with validation, 2-way model binding etc.

Comment: Stephen, thanks a ton. The other S.O. article is good if you already have a solid grasp on the .NET way of doing things, but in our team we have a slew of apps to manage in 7 languages and 11 frameworks using PHP, Ruby On Rails, C++, Java, a couple pure JavaScript websites, and this 30,000-line monstrosity built on .NET. Having to ping pong back and forth never leaves enough time to actually master anything, so that Fiddle is incredibly more enlightening. Thanks so much.